# Поблоковая прокрутка jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-animation

Есть скрипт поблоковой прокрутки на jQuery. Как сделать так чтоб он не перекидывал тебя на первый блок после прокрутки до последнего.

```
var anchors = [];
var currentAnchor = -1;
var isAnimating  = false;
$(function(){
    function updateAnchors() {
        anchors = [];
        $('.anchor').each(function(i, element){
            anchors.push( $(element).offset().bott );
        });
    }
    $('body').on('mousewheel', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        if( isAnimating ) {
            return false;
        }
        isAnimating  = true;
        if( e.originalEvent.wheelDelta >= 0 ) {
            currentAnchor--;
        }else{A
            currentAnchor++;
        }
        if( currentAnchor > (anchors.length - 1) 
           || currentAnchor < 0 ) {
            currentAnchor = 0;
        }
        isAnimating  = true;
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: parseInt( anchors[currentAnchor] )
        }, 500, 'swing', function(){
            isAnimating  = false;
        });
    });
    updateAnchors();   
});
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```
if( currentAnchor > (anchors.length - 1) 
       || currentAnchor < 0 ) {
        currentAnchor = 0;
    }
```

Заменить этот блок. Разделить на два условия. Если меньше 0,то 0. Если больше anchors.length - 1, то ancors.length - 1

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!!